# Control Panel for cv2.createTrackbar with Python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm having trouble to create a control panel for my trackbars. The documentation only gives an explanation for C++ Code.

It states, that "winname can be empty (or NULL) if the trackbar should be attached to the control panel."[See the Doc](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#gaf78d2155d30b728fc413803745b67a9b)

I tried to use NULL and 'NULL' but in Python this will output an error.
I may don't understand a basic principle here, so thank you if you can help me.

this is the output i get when i use the code from Jeru Luke:

[Paint application with the unwanted black windows above the control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR3x4.png)

J.S

Comment: python does not have NULL, it would be None in such case... not 100% sure in this exact function.

Comment: Have a look at the answer I posted and go through [THIS DOCUMENTATION](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_trackbar/py_trackbar.html)

Comment: did the answer work out for you?

Comment: yes it does. sort of. I do get a black windows on top of my control window and it really bothers me. Is there a way to get the control window just to show the trackbars? maybe i want to add a few buttons later but this helps for the start.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a trackbar it is advisable to create a separate window for it all together. Creating a trackbar with same window as the image restricts the space of the image to be displayed.

In the following example I have created a demo where a user can do the following:

1. Draw on a plain surface just like the Paint application on Windows.
2. Adjust the thickness of the paint brush
3. Select a color of your choice from three trackbars namely R, G and B.

In the following code I have used 4 trackbars:

- One for the thickness of the paint brush
- And the remaining three for each of the color channels.

**Code:**

```
'''
PAINT APPLICATION
can draw using a paint brush with varied sizes
'''

import cv2
import numpy as np

drawing = False # true if mouse is pressed
mode = True 
ix, iy = -1, -1

def nothing(x):
    pass

cv2.namedWindow('Controls', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)  #--- window to have all the controls

cv2.createTrackbar("R", "Controls", 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("G", "Controls", 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("B", "Controls", 0, 255, nothing)

cv2.createTrackbar("Paint brush thickness", "Controls",0, 30, nothing)

def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global ix,iy,drawing,mode

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing = True
        ix, iy = x, y

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing == True:
            cv2.circle(img, (x, y), pb_thick, (r, g, b), -1)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing = False
        cv2.circle(img, (x, y), pb_thick, (r, g, b), -1)


img = np.zeros((512, 512, 3), np.uint8)
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image', draw_circle)

while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image',img)

    r = cv2.getTrackbarPos("R", "Controls")
    g = cv2.getTrackbarPos("G", "Controls")
    b = cv2.getTrackbarPos("B", "Controls")

    pb_thick = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Paint brush thickness", "Controls")

    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == ord('m'):
        mode = not mode
    elif k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Notice I have used a window named `Controls` for the trackbar and another window named `image` for the image. I passed in an array of black pixels resembling a blackboard. You can use the same or pass an image.

**Sample Output**

This is how it would look like if you run it:

[image]

Comment: i should have mentioned that i work with linux and when i am running the code you provided, the problem from my comment above occurs. the controlbars are in a different window, but there is also a black image in this window that i cant get rid of. i think this has to do with the highgui and imshow()

Comment: So you want the track bars to be on the drawing pane? By the way the black window is where you do the drawing.

Comment: I want the trackbars just like your example shows. But all I get is a black windows where I can draw and another (smaller) black window with the control bars attached to. There are two separate windows that's fine but the one with the bars shouldn't have a black screen in it

Comment: How do you want that window to be? By the way you can assign a particular shape and color for that window having the control bars.

Answer (score 1):

(Tested, It works)
Using an empty string `""`. Like this:

```
cv2.createTrackbar("bar_name", "", 0, 255, some_callback_func)
```

This will behave just like what you expect in C++. The Trackbar (or button if you wish) will show on the **control panel**.

You need to press `ctl+p` (or click the control panel icon) to pop out and show the control panel window.

The documentation is [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#settrackbarpos). It states that *Note [Qt Backend Only] winname can be empty (or NULL) if the trackbar is attached to the control panel.* The word **empty** is the key. I hope it helps. I have tested, It works.